# What is a reliable cross browser svg way to display a 4mm circle in the middle of the viewport?

Tags: css, svg, viewport

No matter what I try, the displayed circle is not 4mm on a mobile browser. I have tried embedding the svg in an html and using the meta tags and it had no effect.. I have tried using viewport css rules, but they seem unimplemented. I have tried both Firefox mobile and chrome. Is there any other way?

Comment: Perhaps you should post what you tried.

Comment: Thanks allfor the valuable guidance. The problem was there are multiple methods I tried.

Comment: Paulie_D Genius! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mm` is an unusual value in the web world but it is a valid `length` in CSS.

The simplest method for me would be to have an square SVG `viewbox` with a `circle` element 100% wide/tall that takes up the full SVG. This avoids pixel rounding I believe.

Place the SVG in a div and give that `4mm` in `width` then center as desired.

```css
div {
  width: 4mm;
}


/* centering method */


/* but pick your own */

div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
   viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" style="fill:#ff0000"/>

</svg>

</div>
```